# Why does including a module in an active record model cause the model to be redefined as a normal ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blockchain

I have an Active Record model (Listing) that should store some properties in the database while some other properties will be stored in a blockchain (ethereum).

Ideally when a developer does `model_record.save`, the active record save method should be overridden to firstly save the appropriate properties in the blockchain and later proceed to do the normal activerecord save. This procedure applies to most other methods like `.update`, `.destroy`, `.create`.

The following has been achieved by adding a macros level declaration in the model to distinguish the blockchain properties from the normal active record columns

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
   include BlockchainRecord

   self.table_name = "listings"
   blockchain_properties :parcel_no,
                         :description
end
```

A module `BlockchainRecord` has also been included inside the model and includes methods like the ones shown below

```
module BlockchainRecord

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  ...............


  class_methods do
    def blockchain_properties(*props)
      @@blockchain_attributes = props


      define_method :blockchain_attributes do
        props
      end

      props.each do |prop|
        define_method prop do
          if self.instance_variable_defined?("@#{prop}")
            self.instance_variable_get("@#{prop}") 
          else
            if self.address
              val = self.contract.call.send("#{prop}") 
              self.instance_variable_set("@#{prop}", val)
              val
            else
              nil
            end
          end
        end

        # Setter methods
        define_method "#{prop}=" do |arg|
          self.instance_variable_set("@#{prop}", arg)
        end
      end
    end

    def new(props = {})
      model_record = super(props.except(blockchain_attributes))

      blockchainProps = props.slice(*blockchain_attributes)
      blockchainProps.each do |k, v|
        model_record.send("#{k}=", v)
      end

      return model_record
    end
  end

  def save
    if self.address
      blockchain_attributes.each do |prop|
        self.contract.transact_and_wait.send("set_#{prop}", self.send("#{prop}")) 
        sleep(2)
      end
      super
    else
      # in case we call Class.new then Object.save
      contract = Ethereum::Contract.create(file: self.class.contract_file_path)
      key = Eth::Key.new(priv: ENV["PRIVATE_KEY"])
      contract.key = key
      self.address = contract.deploy_and_wait(*(self.attributes.slice(*blockchain_attributes).values))
      super
    end
  end

end
```

The problem occurs when one finishes saving an activerecord object, then later tries something like `Model.count` or `Model.all`.

For example if i did, 
`l = Listing.new(parcel_no: 1234, description: "...", registration_section: "...")` then saved the record `l.save`, that would store the blockchain properties (parcel_no and description) correctly and later call the `.save` provided by ActiveRecord to save the rest of the attributes to the database.

However, when i make a subsequent call like `Listing.count`, that fails with the following error message **NoMethodError: undefined method count for Listing:Class**, and when i check the ancestors of `Listing` i get `[Listing, ActiveSupport::ToJsonWithActiveSupportEncoder, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, MakeMakefile, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, ActiveSupport::Tryable, Kernel, BasicObject]` which just means it no longer inherits from active record base

Why does the overriding of this activerecord .save method in the module cause `Listing` model to no longer inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and how can that be fixed ?

Comment: I am very unclear on your question here but a traditional rails "Model" is always a `Class` (it uses inheritance from the `ActiveRecord::Base` class) including a `Module` does not change this.

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] here.

Comment: @P. Maina, because you said "the save method should be overridden to firstly save the appropriate properties in the blockchain and later proceed to do the normal activerecord save", I believe you would want to use `prepend` instead of `include`, because you want some code to be executed first before running normally, unlike if you use `include` it runs normally first then if the normal method has `super` on it, that's only the time when your "included" code gets called. Yours seemed to have worked because coincidentally I believe Rails has multiple ancestor classes that calls `super`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have edited the question and tried to elaborate a bit more so as to give context. I hope that it is now comprehensive.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Unfortunately even after prepending so that the module is the first in the ancestor chain, the error still comes up.

Comment: @P.Maina yes, I didn't really expect it to be solved with using `prepend`(though it might solve future bugs that you've yet to encounter). Unfortunately, I'm not sure why you said the model gets overwritten or something. I'll try to reproduce if I get the same problem.

Comment: I copied your code in a fresh Rails 5.2.1 project, and created a `Listing` model with attributes `parcel_no`, `description`, and `address`. I commented out anything that has something to do with `Ethereum` above. Then, I did `listing = Listing.new` in rails console was raising an error `NameError undefined local variable or method 'blockchain_attributes' for Listing`, and so I fixed that error by changing `define_method :blockchain_attributes` into `define_singleton_method :blockchain_attributes`. After this, I did `listing.save`, and then however it works: `puts Listing.count` is showing `1`.

Comment: @P.Maina Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce your problem. My current guess is that it's either Rails-version-related, or that the code I commented which is those that relate to `Ethereum::Contract` has something to do with it, or that you have some "other" code that had affected the Model (perhaps via `autoload`-ing? or something). Oh by the way, I tested this on  ruby 2.5.1.

Comment: Make sure there is no other `Listing` class defined in the project.

Comment: Thanks @Jay-ArPolidario and @chumakoff. I have found the solution and it has to do with each of the things you've mentioned. What was happening was that ethereum gem was creating a new class dynamically called Listing through the line `Ethereum::Contract.create()` and as a result when i call `Listing.count` it assumes the class method call was meant for the new dynamically created class and not activerecord model.

Comment: @P.Maina no prob! Good job! :)